# how to use Link properties without the associated style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, jsx

I'm trying to use a link on a component React which looks like that :

[image]

To obtain this result, I have this code :

```
return (

        <>




            <div style={{padding: '1em' }}>

                <span style={{ color: 'grey' }}>#{Command_ID} - </span>
                <span style={{ color: 'purple'}}>{Delivery_Slot}</span><br/>

                <strong>{firstname} {lastName}</strong>
                <p></p>

                {adressPerso},{PostalCode},{city}
            </div>


            <div>

                <IonFooter >
```

At the end of the code, you have an IonFooter This part of the code is'nt showing and inside, you will just have the part about the three components Phone, Map, and "Terminé".

In my case, I just want to allow a personn to click everywhere above the IonFooter part and That's the reason why i use a Link. Nonetheless, when i use one, there are some styling effects :

[image]

I just want to have the same component as before without new styling import by the Link style. concerning my code, I have this :

```
 return (

        <>

        <Link to={`/`} className="item">


            <div style={{padding: '1em' }}>

                <span style={{ color: 'grey' }}>#{Command_ID} - </span>
                <span style={{ color: 'purple'}}>{Delivery_Slot}</span><br/>

                <strong>{firstname} {lastName}</strong>
                <p></p>

                {adressPerso},{PostalCode},{city}
            </div>
            </Link>

            <div>

                <IonFooter >
```

Thank you so much for your help, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: Please paste code instead of screenshots of your code.

Comment: Yeah you're right I did the change ;)